# which Qt environnement do I install to compile and run qtify project?

Tags: qt5, qtquick2

I would like to compile and run the [qtify](http://gitorious.org/+qt-developers/qtify/qtify) project to see a consequent exemple using **desktop components**.This project use:

```
import QtQuick 2.0 // I must have Qt 5 or later
import QtDesktop 1.0 // I search an extension which compile with Qt 5.1
```

I have just installed **Qt 5.1.alpha** this morning, and I would like to install a compatible version of "Qt-desktop-components" wich support **QtDesktop 1.0**.
My **QtCreator version is 2.7.0**.
I tried to install this version of [qtdesktopcomponent](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols) but when I compile with:

```
 `qmake && nmake install`
```

I've got this error: (This comand is used in Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) )

```
C:\Users\Luciole\Downloads\desktop-component\qtquickcontrols>qmake && nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -
f Makefile.Debug

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNIC
ODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"." -I"C:\Users\Luci
ole\Downloads\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.0-alpha\qtbase\include" -I"C:\Use
rs\Luciole\Downloads\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.0-alpha\qtbase\include\QtG
ui" -I"C:\Users\Luciole\Downloads\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.0-alpha\qtbas
e\include\QtCore" -I".moc\debug_shared" -I"C:\Users\Luciole\Downloads\qt-everywh
ere-opensource-src-5.1.0-alpha\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fo.obj\debug_shar
ed\ @C:\Users\Luciole\AppData\Local\Temp\nm54D2.tmp
main.cpp
tools\qmlwidget\main.cpp(43) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtQ
ml': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

The value of my **PATH** is:

```
C:\Users\Luciole\Downloads\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.0-alpha\qtbase\qmake;C:\Users\Luciole\Downloads\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.0-alpha\qtbase\bin;C:\Qt\qtcreator 2.7.0\bin;C:\Git\cmd;C:\Python27;C:\Ruby200;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;
```

And I've verified: I don't have "**QtQml.h**" in my **Qt.5.1.alpha** installation.
What do you think about this? Can you help me to resolve this bug, or can you tell me which version of Qt and qtdesktopcomponent to use? (with the link of the repository please)

Comment: Did you even try [googling the error code](https://www.google.com/search?q=NMAKE+%3A+fatal+error+U1077&aq=f&oq=NMAKE+%3A+fatal+error+U1077&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

If you can't resolve the error (not bug, this likely isn't a bug) I would try contacting the Qtify devs or posting on the [qtify forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtify/forums).

I'm unfamiliar with Qtify, but it sounds like missing a header file QtQml.h is a bad thing...

Comment: dig the make file, I guess it's not reference to the QtQml.h but the "QtQml" directory, make sure it's in include path. I'll try to compile alpha version of qt(which I've been waiting for) few hours latter and let you know.

Comment: @user2261702 Can you please show how did you compile I'm trying 3 days but in vain.
I get the same error even after using msvc2010 "-lpcre16 not found".

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this link](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New-Features-in-Qt-5.1), You don't have to install Qt Desktop, it is included in the package. Name has been change from `Qt Desktop Components` to `Qt Quick Controls`

**Edit:**
Documentation snapshot can find from [here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtquickcontrols/qtquickcontrols-index.html)